# Why is this validation code in the head tag totally ignored once uploaded to the site? It always executes the script inside

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code in the head tag of the site and I want to execute only in the production site. It works locally but it is totally ignored once placed in the site, meaning the script is always executed. There are other pieces of code working with php in the head tag validating scripts and they work fine but this one doesnt do anything to make the script not execute in a development site. I must mention the head tag doesnt have or use any other `get_site_url()` in it. That function works fine anywhere in the site but this is my first time using it in the head tag. **Is there any other way I could do this and make it work??** My code is the following:

```
 <head>
     <?php if (get_site_url() === "https://www.testwebsite.com") : ?>
    
        <script src="https://global.localizecdn.com/localize.js"></script>
        <script>
    
            !function (a) {
                if (!a.Localize) {
                    a.Localize = {};
                    for (var e = ["translate", "untranslate", "phrase", "initialize", "translatePage", "setLanguage", "getLanguage", "getSourceLanguage", "detectLanguage", "getAvailableLanguages", "untranslatePage", "bootstrap", "prefetch", "on", "off", "hideWidget", "showWidget"], t = 0; t < e.length; t++) a.Localize[e[t]] = function () {
                    }
                }
            }(window);
        </script>
    
        <script>
            Localize.initialize({
                key: '12c7ba123a6af',
                rememberLanguage: true
            });
        </script>
    
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: @Bravo exactly that line. I have a dev site and a production site and the script always goes through. It seems like the validation doesnt even exist.

Comment: If I remember correctly, get_site_url() is a WP function. Are you sure that your page(s) are able to execute this function properly in the production environment ?

Comment: the only thing I see that is different to *documented examples* is the space before `:` ... have you tried `<?php if (get_site_url() === "https://www.testwebsite.com"): ?>`

Comment: @KenLee yeah actually it works in development and production anywhere in the body tag but not the head tag. Does the <?php wp_head(); ?> function being after the code I placed have to do anything with it?? It works locally so I dont get the issue.

Comment: @Bravo - It's completely fine to have a space before the `:`. The PHP interpreter doesn't care and won't execute it any differently.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - then there' probably more to the code than the OP is letting on

Comment: \Instead of using get_site_url(), please use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to do the job So please use `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="www.testwebsite.com")`

Comment: @KenLee Ill try this. It seems good to me.